# Is it safe to use the Shopping Cart Class in Codeigniter 3.1.8

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, cart

I have read several old posts regarding Shopping Cart Class in Codeigniter and found that it is not recommended to use. But I also read that the answers are regarding 2.x version.
Now I am using Codeigniter 3.1.8 version in my projects. It is safe and good to use the Codeigniter Cart Class now in my projects?

Comment: The Cart library is DEPRECATED and should not be used. It is currently only kept for backwards compatibility.

Comment: @Gulshan Thanks for the prompt response. Can you please suggest me an alternate best solution for codeigniter?

Comment: You can check this topic, they propose variants for your question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31077476/is-it-safe-to-use-codeigniter-shopping-cart

Comment: @Fizik26 As I mentioned in the description that I have gone through some older threads, and this one is one of them. Its 2019 now, am I am looking for a practical solution today. Answers posted in that thread are years old.

Comment: @ITSagar you can manage your cart by session or database

Answer (score 2):

The primary (and very valid) objection to the shopping cart in v2 of CodeIgniter (CI) was the security of the session class. Starting with CI v3 the session class was rewritten making it as safe as PHP sessions can be.

The shopping cart class is deprecated mostly because there are several third-party solutions that are more robust and actively maintained. The cart will not be included in CI v4.

Other than the deprecated status there isn't any reason (that I know about) not to use it. It isn't anywhere close to "full-featured" but it is a fine base to build on. That said, there are other free solutions out there that can be integrated into CI with less effort than extending the included class.